# variable_del wildcard when uninstalling a module

Tags: 7, configuration

I have lot of variables created in a module. Is there any wildcard when deleting variables using `variable_del`.

```
Ex1: variable_del($key . '_campaign_text_*');
Ex2: variable_del($key . '_campaign_text_%');
```

Will any of these workout?

Comment: No they won't. Wild cards don't work. You'd need to first query the DB and then loop through your results deleting them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try db_delete but handle with caution.

Example :

```
db_delete('variable')
->condition('name', '_campaign_text_%','LIKE')
->execute();
cache_clear_all('variables', 'cache_bootstrap');
```